# UIButton's Image is larger than background image

Tags: swift, autolayout

Here is the background image of my button.   [image]

When user click on it I add the foreground image programmatically but it's size is not the same than UIButton and it's background image.

it is like that [image] when it should be like that [image]

this is the code for the image adding

```
sender.imageView?.alpha = 1
sender.setImage(UIImage(named: "Selected"), for: UIControl.State.normal)
```

and here is the parameters for the button

[image]
[image]

I didn't have this problem when the Button size was fixed to 80x80 but it was not responsive enough for some iPhones so now the constraints make it a rectangle that can grow or shrink depending of devices

Do you have an idea where is this problem from ? I already tried to use scaleAspectFill but it doesn't work.

Comment: Please show code and the button Attributes Inspector parameters (notably for View Content Mode).

Comment: @claude31 that's okay I updated the post

Comment: "it should be like that" Why should it be? It seems to me the button is behaving exactly as expected. The only surprising thing is that `setImage` does anything at all, as you have opted in to UIButtonConfiguration.

Comment: Did you try different Content Mode in background configuration.

Comment: @matt No by default there isn't the image "selected". It appears when you click on the UIButton that only has a background image by default. But when the image appears, the size isn't the same than the background image. On some iPhones, it is smaller, on others it is taller.

Comment: @claude31 yes I tried but it seems it is not working

Comment: @GuillaumeBOURLART - edit your question and include the actual png images you are using... what you've posted is confusing, as you are showing different "grid" images but it's not clear what your "background" and "foreground" images really are.